# If $\,-u''+u=f$, then $\,\|u\|_{L^s}+\|u'\|_{L^q}+\|u''\|_{L^p}\le c\|f\|_{L^p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, singular-integrals

> Let $u\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ ([Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)) be a solution of the equation 
>   $$
> -u''+u=f, \quad \text{where}\,\,\,f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}).
> $$ 
>   Show that for all $1\leq p,q,s \leq \infty$, there exists a $c>0$, 
>   such that 
>   $$
> \|u\|_{L^s(\mathbb{R})}+\|u'\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R})}+\|u''\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}
> \le c\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}.
> $$
>   This reminds me of the generalized Hölder inequality $$\int fgh \leq ||f||_{L^s(\mathbb{R})}||g||_{L^q(\mathbb{R})}||h||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}$$ where $\frac1s+\frac1q+\frac1p=1$. 
>   How can I write $u$ as an integral $I(f)$?

Comment: Not well formulated. Do you mean, *For every $p\in[1,\infty]$, there exist $s,q\in[1,\infty]$ and $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4>0$ such that the following inequality holds*?

Comment: Yes, thanks, edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform we obtain
$$
u(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-|x-y|}f(y)\,dy, \\
u'(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-|x-y|}\text{sgn}(x-y)\,f(y)\,dy,
$$ 
Using [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) we obtain
$$
\|u\|_q\le c_0(q)\|f\|_p,\quad \|u’\|_s\le c_1(s)\|f\|_p
$$
where
$$
c_0(q)=\frac{1}{2}\big\|\mathrm{e}^{-|x|}\big\|_{q'}, \quad
c_1(s)=\frac{1}{2}\big\|\mathrm{e}^{-|x|}\big\|_{s'}
$$
and $q',s'$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q'}=\frac{1}{q}+1, \quad
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{s'}=\frac{1}{s}+1.
$$
and
$$
\|u''\|_p=\|u-f\|_p\le \|f\|_p+c_0(p)\|f\|_p
$$
Altogether
$$
\|u\|_q+\|u'\|_s+\|u''\|_p\le\big(1+c_0(p)+c_0(q)+c_1(s)\big)\|f\|_p.
$$

Comment: I believe there should be a derivative in the bound $||u||_s$.

Comment: Correct! I made the corrections.